# Error on Step 2 of Authorization Code Grant :: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"unauthorized_client"}

Tags: authorization

I am using the Integration Key from my App setup on the Admin screen for client_id and the secret key for client_secret.

$test_str = $client_id.":".$client_secret;
$integrator_and_secret_key = "Basic " . utf8_decode(base64_encode($test_str));

```
    $headers = [
        "Authorization" => $integrator_and_secret_key,
        "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    ];
    $postData = [
        "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
        "code" => $code
    ];
    $url = "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token";


    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

    $response = json_decode($curl_response, true);


    curl_close($curl);
    echo $curl_response;
```

and the response returns: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"unauthorized_client"}

Here is the code returned in Step 1: eyJ0eXAiOiJNVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiNjgxODVmZjEtNGU1MS00Y2U5LWFmMWMtNjg5ODEyMjAzMzE3In0.AQsAAAABAAYABwAAqjn82r7XSAgAADbAQ9u-10gCADiypKkwcrtFo5SpIKqK2z0VAAEAAAAYAAEAAAAFAAAADQAkAAAAMzY2Mzg2MWUtMTgzMS00Y2EzLTgwODctOGU1YTZlM2EwZDJlIgAkAAAAMzY2Mzg2MWUtMTgzMS00Y2EzLTgwODctOGU1YTZlM2EwZDJlMAAAqjn82r7XSBIAAQAAAAsAAABpbnRlcmFjdGl2ZTcAWKaBqQaIn06g8bRJjsmteg.p354fORWWaAGh1UZBSP4tYCaKxHIVY1ylUenJs8JWHDQfNsdGFhjKn36uhNCYgU9-Vy6qlDpCtRxOARgKUXGBKCxyaLsMnXafevT2zIdVh_2TUD1ihTNTDSA5EFfD6eQWHN-7Ex66anAqMkylQk9fPEGa8og_duNrNJ8-IJyDRs8tRQX_WDj9pGbDOIpPC246dMcKikD2bi0-giC39LEjh1RSiD6WKTeiBxIF-YTYqtXtC31uzfjzL0iXuNXcWat_Vb-2FC_DDoOfHl4ZgwjIb0wvmtOz1XLvTi64ljmoYs9Y1bNyiYpyi5N06z7EfSbbLyI7482MmaqBhkfwRfCfg

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: can you add more information about the architecture and platform, esp if there are some Tags that match?

Comment: My app is built using PHP and Codeigniter 3.1. The app is riding on a dedicated LAMP server

Comment: And trying to accomplish an Authorization Code Grant API authentication process (Step 2)

Answer (score 1):

Your header needs to be formatted as follows:

```
$headers = [
    "Authorization: $integrator_and_secret_key",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
];
```

Keyed arrays are not valid headers for cURL.